# Height of element is what's left of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How should i set a div's height to be what's left of the viewport from its start minus 20 pixels? Parent DIV is 100% of the viewport, and i need the child to expand until the parent's end.

Parent div's jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  windowHeight = $(window).height() - 0;
  $('.slide').css('min-height', windowHeight);
});
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ which demonstrates what your trying to do?  (include your html and jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a parent div with a 100% height, and inside it you have something that's 20px high and then something that should stretch to the bottom? (Please be clear in your question, or include a code example as a jsfiddle and/or a screenshot).

Look at this simple example

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"> 
        Heading 
    </div>
    <div class="strecth">
        Stretching content
    </div>
</div>
```

The styles to achieve what I think you mean:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    height: 20px;
}
.stretch {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

The padding of 20px is rendered as part of the 100%, so effectively the contents of your `.stretch` will be 100% - 20px high (which is what you want), but there is an offset of 20px (the padding) that pushes it down. Then I use the negative margin to undo the offset by pulling the div back up 20px. The effect is that the visible contents are exactly 100% - 20px of height, which is what you wanted.

See the live code (I added some colors for emphasis, and had to set some extra height to body and html because jsFiddle will not do that automatically, you should not need that):
]http://jsfiddle.net/48aET/